# Multi-Factor Authentication in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

Hi I was given a task by my boss to find out if it is possible to have a two factor authentication implemented on our databases. We currently have them on our servers but we want to implement them on our databases as well. Does anyone know if Microsoft or any third part  offers this functionality and if so how do they work?

Comment: It might be better to ask about this at [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), or possibly at [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD supports MFA and you can setup Azure SQL Database/Data Warehouse to utilize Azure AD.  There is some complexity to it but this article should get you started.  If you need on-prem I'm pretty sure you are out of luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication